# Fixing Master Boot Record From Linux After Windows Corrupts It

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot

I bought a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop, and setup Ubuntu 10.04 to dual boot alongside Windows 7. Regrettably, when activating the wireless, I did something in Windows 7 that caused it to overwrite or corrupt the master boot record, so now when I reboot I get the message "No bootable devices found". Is there an easy way to fix this, perhaps via a Linux LiveCD, or do I have to wipe out everything and reinstall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 uses GRUB2 as its bootloader which should save you some time using the guide above.